# How to add File of different version to SVN?

Tags: svn

I have my repository in below format.

```
/svn/project/trunk/file1,file2,dir1,dir2 (file & directory under trunk),
/svn/project/branches
/svn/project/tags
```

I have created one branch for trunk with head revision as V1 (/svn/project/branches/v1/file1,file2,dir1,dir2 ) .this is the one am using with my working copy.

Now i want to upgrade my application it means the dir2 folder am using will be different in the upgraded version.let say file1,file2,dir1,dir2 these are the file am using.when i upgrade my project the dir2 will get change but other files will be same.it means the upgraded version also will have same directory dir2 and files name under this dir2 will be same between the old and upgraded version but content of the file will be different.How i can revision my file?
Please advice....

Comment: What do you mean by "upgrade"? I have tried to read your question  times but I still can't visualize what you are asking or trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you want is simple using SVN:

```
$> cd /path/to/your/working/copy
$> svn copy http://yourRepoAddress/project/branches/v1 http://yourRepoAddress/project/branches/v2
$> svn switch http://yourRepoAddress/project/branches/v2
... then you can modify all the files you want inside dir2 or elsewhere ...
$> svn commit -m "Changed files in dir2"
```

And you're done.

`svn copy` creates a new branch, then `svn switch`moves your working copy to that branch, and finally `svn commit` allows you to push your change to the server.

Comment: Am using one frame work. when i upgrade my framework to latest version all files in the application will not change , only the core library will change.

Comment: If the framework you are using is versionned using SVN also, you can look at [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html). You can browse [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1535477/1374267) to find more information about how to use externals.